# Force figure placement

Tags: floats, positioning

I found this thread:
[Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)
where it tells me that I have to use `\usepackage{float}` and then using `\begin{figure}[H]` instead.
However I have the problem that in this example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\section{blablabla}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\epswidtha\textwidth, angle=90]{fig1.eps}
    \caption{BKLABLABLABLALBABLA ABLSfd BLABLA}
    \label{A2.1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\epswidtha\textwidth, angle=90]{fig2.eps}
    \caption{BKLABLABLABLALBABLA ABLSfd BLABLA}
    \label{A2.2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

latex places fig1 at the bottom of the page and there is a big blank after the section writing...fig2 is then placed on the next page which I do not want! I (no matter what issues latex has, I dont care!) want that figure there...
I did not post an entire mwe, because with specific pictures not being present it didn't seem to make sense.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please post a complete MWE. Replace your pictures with `example-image-a` or `example-image-b` or, for a real thrill, `example-image-c`, which everyone has. Or specify the dimensions and pass `demo` to `graphicx`. Presumably, your second figure is too large to fit on the page. Make the page bigger, delete something or move the figures. The white space is because you've insisted on very poor placement and LaTeX has to do something to finish the page.

Comment: You could use the available example images to provide a MWE. As `example-imabe-a`, `example-imabe-b` etc. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231741/105447.

Comment: Seems from your description that there simply isn't room on the page for both figures on that page. You could put both images in the same `figure` environment to force them to be on the same page (page breaks cannot occur inside a `figure` env), but you might need to reduce the size of the images. That the first figure ends up on the bottom of the page and not immediately below the `\section`, is possibly because you're using a class with `\flushbottom`, similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56091/

Comment: In addition to other comments: I suggest not using `figure` and `[H]`, but using the package `caption` with its `\captionof{figure}{blabla}` macro. Just put all the contents in a `center` or `minipage` environment (the latter avoids page breaks). The idea: If you don't want it to float, do not use a float.

Comment: @Phillip: I will try that out. I did use figure, because I though if I do not the figure counting is affected by it? Is it?

Comment: One could not tell the difference between an image in a `center` environment with `\captionof{figure}{bla}` and a true `figure`. The integration is seemless, you can freely mix both, e.g. use figures for things that should float and the other method for things that should remain fixed. (There might however be a problem if a floating figure is defined before a fixed one, but placed later due to space constraints. I do not know, because I have never had that problem.)

Comment: Use the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/2975) to the linked question, i.e. don't use a float environment when you don't want the content to float.

Comment: Use the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/2975) to the linked question, i.e. don't use a float environment when you don't want the content to float.